# Can I copy wireless drivers from one Ubuntu to another?

Tags: wireless, usb

I'm having the hardest time with a desktop install using a Cable Matters N-150 Wireless card.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Seems to pick up the card no problem, but when I install it I get Kernel Panic's... Ubuntu 14-15 install/run fine, but do not pick up the card.

Can I somehow copy the drivers/etc from Ubuntu 16 to 15/14?

Comment: the latest nightly build of xenial/16.04 is working... thanks again for any replies. I'm going to try and close this :)

Answer (score 1):

i dont recommended you to copy drive with any ways if you can go to terminal then

sudo lspci -v

and write name of network card  and we "ll help you

sorry for my bad English

Comment: thanks so much for the reply. unfortunately, with ubuntu 14/15 sudo lspci -v doesn't return any network cards.  I'll boot it again and see if I can't copy/paste the output of lspci... thanks again @Muqteda

Comment: if you can"t copy/paste send screenshot @WestonWatson

Comment: Do you mean network card has correct drive but network card is unloaded (won"t work)